# MIP formulation for a lower semi-continuous function

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, constraint, big-m

How can I formulate in mixed linear programming (a set of constraints) the following issue.
I have an objective function $\underset{x}{\max} g(x)$.
I need to convert a continuous linear function $f(x)$ (with $x$ real) such that when $f(x) < 0$ it passes 0 to the objective function and when $f(x) \ge 0$ it passes $f(x)$.

I have the indicator constraints formulated as

\begin{equation}
y \ge \frac{1}{M}f(x) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y \le 1 + \frac{1}{M}f(x) \tag{2}
\end{equation}

with $M$ sufficiently big, but I am missing the link from $f(x$) to $g(x)$ such that when

\begin{equation}
f(x) < 0 \quad \text{then} \quad g(x) = 0
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
f(x) \ge 0 \quad \text{then} \quad g(x) = f(x)
\end{equation}
with $g(x) \ge 0$.

Any guidance on this?

Comment: In other words, you want to maximize $\max(f(x),0)$.

Comment: Crossposted (duplicate) at Math.SE:  [MIP formulation for a lower semi-continuous function, with a null or positiv domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4817347/572874)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to maximize $\max(f(x),0)$.  Assume $L \le f(x) \le U$ for constants $L$ and $U$.  Maximize $g(x)$ subject to
$$
0 \le g(x) \le U y \\
0 \le g(x) - f(x) \le (0-L)(1-y) \\
y \in \{0,1\}
$$

Comment: what about if L=0 and U=+inf?

Comment: $L=0$ is fine, but $U$ needs to be finite.  Also, $L=0$ means that $f(x) \ge 0$, so $\max(f(x),0)=f(x)$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Just think of $g$ as a variable.  The formulation I proposed enforces $g=\max(f(x),0)$.

Comment: many thanks. I think I got it. It's precisely what I need. making L safelly small and U safelly big generalizes the case.